# Access hdfs cluster from pydoop

Tags: python-3.x, filesystems, hdfs

I have hdfs cluster and python on the same google cloud platform. I want to access the files present in the hdfs cluster from python. I found that using pydoop one can do that but I am struggling with giving it right parameters maybe. Below is the code that I have tried so far:-

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
import pydoop

pydoop.hdfs.hdfs(host='url of the file system goes here',
                 port=9864, user=None, groups=None)

"""
 class pydoop.hdfs.hdfs(host='default', port=0, user=None, groups=None)

    A handle to an HDFS instance.

    Parameters

            host (str) – hostname or IP address of the HDFS NameNode. Set to an empty string (and port to 0) to connect to the local file system; set to 'default' (and port to 0) to connect to the default (i.e., the one defined in the Hadoop configuration files) file system.

            port (int) – the port on which the NameNode is listening

            user (str) – the Hadoop domain user name. Defaults to the current UNIX user. Note that, in MapReduce applications, since tasks are spawned by the JobTracker, the default user will be the one that started the JobTracker itself.

            groups (list) – ignored. Included for backwards compatibility.


"""

#print (hdfs.ls("/vs_co2_all_2019_v1.csv"))
```

It gives this error:-

```
RuntimeError: Hadoop config not found, try setting HADOOP_CONF_DIR
```

And if I execute this line of code:-

```
print (hdfs.ls("/vs_co2_all_2019_v1.csv"))
```

nothing happens. But this "vs_co2_all_2019_v1.csv" file does exist in the cluster but is not available at the moment, when I took screenshot.

My hdfs screenshot is shown below:

[image: HDFS structure]

and the credentials that I have are shown below:

[image]

Can anybody tell me that what am I doing wrong? Which credentials do I need to put where in the pydoop api? Or maybe there is another simpler way around this problem, any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: question:  normal hdfs port is 8020.  why does your request show port 9864?

Comment: because in my hdfs cluster it shows that the port is 9864, when I browse to google cloud/dataproc/clusters/hdfs_nodename in the address bar it shows port by :9864.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
import pydoop

hdfs_object = pydoop.hdfs.hdfs(host='url of the file system goes here',
                               port=9864, user=None, groups=None)
hdfs_object.list_directory("/vs_co2_all_2019_v1.csv")
```

or simply:

```
hdfs_object.list_directory("/")
```

Keep in mind that `pydoop.hdfs` module is not directly related with the `hdfs` class (`hdfs_object`). Thus, the connection that you established in the first command is not used in `hdfs.ls("/vs_co2_all_2019_v1.csv")`